# How to receive the verify data from bank in Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm using this code to receive the verify data from bank API (Persian bank)

```
saleReferenceId = long.Parse(queryString["SaleReferenceId"].ToString()); 
saleOrderId = long.Parse(queryString["SaleOrderId"].ToString()); 
resultCode_bpPayRequest = queryString["ResCode"].ToString();
```

But After the user has paid the amount the SaleRefrenceId and other fields are empty. I wanna know how to receive these fields from bank API?

I used to receive it in asp.net.mvc by

`Request.param["saleReferenceId"]`

But know, I don't know how to take it in ASP.netcore

Plz help me with

Comment: How did you get the data,from querystring? You can try `HttpContext.Request.Query["SaleReferenceId"].ToString();`

Comment: Yeah I did but that didn't work for me, The data come from header

Comment: if (HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("SaleReferenceId", out var traceValue))
                {
                    saleReferenceId = long.Parse(traceValue);
                }
                if (HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("SaleOrderId", out var traceValue2))
                {
                    saleOrderId = long.Parse(traceValue2);
                }
                if (HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("ResCode", out var traceValue3))
                {
                    resultCode_bpPayRequest = traceValue3;
                }

Comment: I used this code too but still doesn't work for me!